# Will I miss cool stuff if I restart?

Tags: dead-rising-2

I'm currently playing Dead Rising 2 on the Xbox 360 and the game is getting increasingly hostile towards me. I have to keep rushing for toilets like I've eaten nothing but mexican for a week or else I get brutalized by psychopaths, tigers and mercenaries and forfeit everything I've been doing for the past four hours in game time.

I understand that restarting the game will let me keep my current level (13) and combo cards, and it's starting to tempt me more and more. The problem is I really don't want to miss any potential achievements or other nice rewards for completing the game without restarting once. Are there any? Will there be any other negative consequences for restarting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can view all the achievements [here](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/dead-rising-2/achievements/).  There's none related to restarting or not, and I'm 99% percent sure there are no other benefits to a "single life" playthrough.

In fact, it's quite impossible to do a lot of the things in the game without restarting, and designed to be that way.  I understand the aspect of wanting to challenge yourself and have a "perfect play", but you'll enjoy yourself much more if you just go with it.

<sub>Disclaimer: I worked on Dead Rising 2.</sub>

Comment: Cool, I'll take your word for it and restart. :) Thanks!